# TextBlocks jump a little after transitions

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, transition

I'm applying EntranceThemeTransition to StackPanel that contains bunch of controls. When I show a popup everything works fine except TextBlocks that jump a little after animation.

Here is a video of that:
http://screencast.com/t/VXSiti6Mh

Here is code I'm using:

```
<StackPanel Margin="40">
    <StackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EntranceThemeTransition FromHorizontalOffset="100" />
        </TransitionCollection>
    </StackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Filter Results" />
    <TextBlock >Show</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

The popup itself has PaneThemeTransition set as it's Transition.

Any ideas why it could be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround - wrap each textblock with StackPanel. Clearly it's not ideal but it works.

I still wonder if there is a way to fix it without hacks...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
UseLayoutRounding="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
```

on the container.

Comment: I havent, but i'll try it and will post here.